# How do I understand Hair particles? Because nothing i doing makes sense to me

Tags: mesh, particles, hair

I'm relatively new to Blender so forgive me, if I'm unable to accurately depict my problem.

I've been struggling with Hair particles for almost a month trying and I haven't been able to find a solution for my problems. Okay so, the first problem I have is with Deflect Emitter; which I'm told is used to prevent hair from going through the mesh, but seems to have no effect whatsoever, I even changed the settings from how close the particles are to the mesh, but the particles still fall through.

I either use the settings, of 0.5 and 0.9, which causes the particles to fall through, and between 1.2 and 1.9 which repels the particles erratically. causing the ends of the particles to still go through the mesh. I've tried to duplicate a scalp mesh, but this does not help either. I read somewhere that I should add a collision to the mesh and turn on hair dynamics, but this frustrated me more, because though I got the mesh pretty close, but this has caused a huge conflict in the Hair particle vertices separating and I don't know how to correct it, but of course the hair still falls through the mesh.

My model has long dynamic hair, so a bit of her hair is touching her skin, so I need it not to go through the mesh. I turn off Hair dynamics and collision, because I could not get the desired results without, the outrageous lagging of the software, and constant crashing.

I'm in the process of understanding Geometry Nodes, so if there is a way to fix this in Geometry Nodes that is helpful. Though any explanation will be beneficial.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe you should upload your file on https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question. Probably not everything, only the separate scalp and maybe you can leave just the mesh of the head as collision object in it as well. Otherwise I do not know where to start troubleshooting, are the normals correct, is the scale applied etc. and then there are dozens of settings in the particle system we might need to check...